# Accessing html form input type=text using jquery from a windows forms webbrowser-control

Tags: jquery, webbrowser-control

I have two elements on my Windows Forms application:
Webbrowser-Control
Button

Inside of the webbrowser-control I show a very simple html-form with two input type=text.
I press the button and get access to both text fields.

Last year at the Qt developer conference there was a quite good presentation: http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/04/17/jquery-and-qwebelement/

```
void highlightAllLinks() {
    QString code = "$('a').each( function () { 
                        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow') 
                    })";
    view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(code);
}
```

But I have to do this with .net and Windows Forms. Anyone knowing a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

See if this link helps, it's a similar question to yours --> [Using jQuery in WinForms desktop app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352159/using-jquery-in-winforms-desktop-app)

EDIT:

I actually found code in another, better link: 
[How to inject Javascript in WebBrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/webbrowser-control-from-net-how-to-inject-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Found something:
http://metadeveloper.blogspot.com/2008/10/mashing-up-jquery-and-windows-forms.html

Quite easy to understand - really nice!

Comment: Nice.  I found that too but didn't see the link to the actual source code.  Reading is fundamental :).  Make sure you accept your own answer in this case so that people know your question has been answered.

Comment: The link to the source code is under the screenshot in the middle of the text:
"You can download the whole thing here. (Very 0.1 but posted as an example/idea - just use the next / previous buttons to view some photos, get a feel of things)."